# BorderStyle: Dash not work correct in react native

Tags: react-native, border

I don't know why my dash is very bad. 
My react-native version: 0.57.
here is my screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/koeNu.jpg

```
<View style={{ height: '80%', alignSelf: 'center',borderStyle:'dashed',borderRadius:1,borderWidth:1,borderColor: Color.dashColor}} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad in what way? the number of dashes? the quality?
I assume it is the number because of how small they are,
try using a larger border radius and a more sutle color like :

```
> #E0E0E0

> #EEEEEE
```

more info might be needed though

Comment: I think it bad because it have both Right & Left border. when i set single right or left border it warning: unsupported dashed/dotted.

Comment: i read somewhere last night that most people are not getting it to work. i will have to test it my self